# Auto-Layout - Portrait and Landscape with one Storyboard using constraint priorities?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

How should I approach implementing the following layout using Auto-Layout?

Can I do this with one set of constraints, e.g. using different constraint priorities? Or do I need to make it two separate definitions – If so, how do I transition seamlessly between them?

[image]

The Big Box (image)

- should always be centred on the screen taking as much space as possible (minus a little padding to the closest border)
- square, ratio 1:1
- actual size dynamic depening on available screen estate

Small Box (button)

- square, ratio 1:1, fixed size (e.g. 150 × 150 pt)

**Portrait**

The small box should be below the big box

**Landscape**

The small box should move to the right side due to limited vertical space, again with equal distance to the big box and border (but this time the one on the right)

Ideally I'd like to setup the constraints directly in its Storyboard. However in case I need to create separate versions I'd prefer code.

Comment: This is why we have SizeClasses.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to use code to update the constraints dynamically. I use [this framework](https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout) provided by another SO user.

You'd need to override `updateConstraints` and store the current orientation in a property so you don't keep updating the constraints unnecessarily (that will cause performance issues). In your layout, there is probably only one constraint that would need replacing; I'd probably store a reference to that as a property too so I didn't have to look it up. Then your `updateConstraints` implementation simply removes that constraint and replaces it with the portrait/landscape equivalent. Use the `autoPinEdge:toEdge:ofView:withOffset:` method provided by the framework and you can use the offset to manage the spacing between the views.

For example:

> self.savedConstraint = [smallView autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:largeView withOffset:kSpacing];

In your case, I think you only need to replace the constraint that pins the top edge of the small view to the bottom of the larger one (portrait) and replace it with one that pins the leading edge of the small view to the trailing edge of the small one. You might also need to manage a constraint from the small view's bottom/trailing edge to the bottom/right edge of the superview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it by code. In your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //Set width and height of big box
    [bigBox addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bigBox
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:nil
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:BIG_BOX_WIDTH]];

    [bigBox addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bigBox
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:nil
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                      multiplier:1 constant:BIG_BOX_HEIGHT]];

    //Center big box in super view
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bigBox
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bigBox
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

    //Set width and height of small box
    [smallBox addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:smallBox
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:nil
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:SMALL_BOX_WIDTH]];

    [smallBox addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:smallBox
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:nil
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                      multiplier:1 constant:SMALL_BOX_HEIGHT]];


}

- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        [self updateViewConstraints];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (void)updateViewConstraints
{


    //Remove previous position constraints between big box and small box.
    for(NSLayoutConstraint *boxPosition in self.boxPositionConstraints) {
        [self.view removeConstraint:boxPosition];
    }
    self.boxPositionConstraints = nil;

    //Check orientation and create new visual format layout between big box and small box
    BOOL layoutIsPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);
    NSString *axisPrefix = layoutIsPortrait ? @"V" : @"H:";
    NSLayoutFormatOptions alignmentOption = layoutIsPortrait ? NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX : NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY;
    NSString *layoutFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:[bigBox]-%@-[smallBox]", axisPrefix, BOX_DISTANCES];

    NSDictionary *bindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bigBox, smallBox);
    self.boxPositionConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:layoutFormat
                                                                              options:alignmentOption
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:bindings];
    [self.view addConstraints:self.boxPositionConstraints];

}
```

From your diagrams, I'm assuming the size of your big box is dependent on the width of the device. If so, you can just create condition on the correct size depending on the device used. Since there are only a few iOS devices, I'm assuming this is easier right now than having it's size dependent on the size of the screen.